# I am unable to launch the Chrome browser even though the key and values is correct in system.set property file

Tags: selenium, webdriver

```
package selsample;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class selclass[enter image description here][1] {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\username\\Selenium.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://app.doselect.com/test/bvd9b/feedback");
        

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Mohini, Issue looks like with the path you have entered for chromedriver.exe. Exe doesn't exist in E:\ drive. 
1) make sure chromedriver_win32.exe exists in E:\ driver  so enter path as "E:\\chromedriver_win32.exe" or copy chromedriver_win32.exe in to the project itself and  you can  use absolute path for your test. 

Please have a look my github project for details. https://github.com/ryadav14/learnautomation

Comment: Actually the driver is located at that path and path is also correct but still getting same error

Comment: you can DM me on linkedin, happy to have a look and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `chromedriver.exe` is not available in the mentioned that's why it shows driver executable does not exist, you can set it as below

Create a folder in your project named `driver` just copy the chromedriver.exe to that folder (eg. /driver/chromedriver.exe)

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",path+"\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
```

You check this that might help you just follow the steps